# How to get around this "Internal PatchWiz Error occurred Cannot create folder" error when building WiX PCP patching targets in parallel?

Tags: msbuild, wix, msi-patch

I am trying to build a pair of WiX patch projects (the Patch Creation ones..) in parallel however my 64-bit configuration one always fails with PatchWiz errors:

```
  INFO: Passed all of the main control parameter validation to PatchWiz, now calling the next 5 phases.
  INFO: Phase I:    Entered validation and processing phase.
  ERROR: Internal PatchWiz Error occurred.
  ERROR:    The Last Error Received is: 0x20 (32)
  INFO: Temporary folder is about to be cleaned out and deleted: C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Local\Temp\~pcw_tmp.tmp
  ERROR: Internal PatchWiz Error occurred.
  ERROR:    The Last Error Received is: 0x91 (145)
  ERROR: During cleanup, could not delete the temporary folder: C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Local\Temp\~pcw_tmp.tmp.
  ERROR:    The Last Error Received is: 0x91 (145)
```

I tried:

- cleaning temp folder before running.
- switching the configuration order.
- adding a sleep/timeout between executions

with no luck.

Here is my build.proj I am executing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Import Project="packages\MSBuild.Extension.Pack.1.8.0\build\net40\MSBuild.Extension.Pack.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\MSBuild.Extension.Pack.1.8.0\build\net40\MSBuild.Extension.Pack.targets')" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProductVersion>1.1.2</ProductVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Compile32">
    <MSBuild Targets="Build" Projects="Hotfix_Patch.wixproj"
             Properties="Configuration=Debug;Platform=x86;ProductVersion=$(ProductVersion)"  />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Compile64">
    <MSBuild Targets="Build" Projects="Hotfix_Patch.wixproj"
         Properties="Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64;ProductVersion=$(ProductVersion)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Build" >
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Parallel TaskAction="BuildTargetsInParallel" Targets="Compile64;Compile32"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Am I at the mercy of PatchWiz? Or is there something I might be doing wrong? Any hack ideas? (and don't say I'm doing it wrong by Patching/MSP in the first place! I realize that! Aside from this I'm a Major Upgrade MSI kind of guy).

Answer (score 0):

The second patch creation process is trying to trample over the first's temp files luckily C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Local\Temp\~pcw_tmp.tmp. is just a default. You can to specify another buildarch specific temp folder:-

If using MSIMSP.exe use /f on your cmd line 
 [see msimsp.exe docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370324(v=vs.85).aspx)

If using patchwiz directly, it's a parameter of UICreatePatchPackage [see PatchWiz docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372095(v=vs.85).aspx)

p.s. Was a good day when I found this out :)